# Building fast Android app - Java or native?

Tags: java, android, c++, c

I'm about to start building an Android app (I'm currently working on the web service and the database) and I'd like to know if there's a significant difference on the app speed between using Java or coding directly into C or C++.

The app doesn't contain any complex graphics or physics and its speed depends mostly on the transfer speed of several Objects to and from a REST web service.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend doing it in Java, as does Google. The only purpose of the NDK is to make porting preexisting codebases significantly easier.

Comment: "its speed depends mostly on the transfer speed of several Objects to and from a REST web service" -- the "transfer speed" is governed by the Internet connection and has little or nothing to do with the speed of the programming language.

Comment: Use Java until you must bind a native lib or profiling shows a hot spot where the modest speed advantage of native code will really make a difference.  It is much harder to make native code robust and correct than Java and then again harder to maintain.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Google says](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) you probably should just stick with Java:

> Before downloading the NDK, you should understand that the NDK will not benefit most apps. As a developer, you need to balance its benefits against its drawbacks. Notably, using native code on Android generally does not result in a noticable performance improvement, but it always increases your app complexity. In general, you should only use the NDK if it is essential to your app—never because you simply prefer to program in C/C++.
>
> Typical good candidates for the NDK are self-contained, CPU-intensive operations that don't allocate much memory, such as signal processing, physics simulation, and so on. When examining whether or not you should develop in native code, think about your requirements and see if the Android framework APIs provide the functionality that you need.

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend using the NDK, since you have mentioned that you are building this from the ground up for android. Google specifically says [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) that you shouldn't use the NDK for the reasons mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Java and consume your REST web services with Spring for Android. It's too easy consume them. Currently I've got one published app in Android Play Store using it and the source code is in GitHub, there you can take a look.

Good luck!